# how do I write a Container<T> trait and use its partial specialization as function params

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say a class is a `MyContainer<T>` if it has

```
size_t size()
T& operator[](size_t index)
const T& operator[](size_t index)
```

and I want to write a template function that accept a specific version of MyContainer, for example any container that indexes int values and float values

```
float add(const MyContainer<int> &left, const MyContainer<float> &right);
```

and use it like

```
vector<int> a;
some_custom_vector<float> b;
float res = add(a, b);
```

How can I achieve that?

I cannot use `auto` because I want to specify inner type

```
// can not specify inner type
template<typename MyContainer>
float add(const MyContainer &left, const MyContainer &right);

// can not specify inner type either
auto add(const auto &left, const auto &right);
```

I also tried using `template <template <class> class MyContainer>`, but the compiler can't infer the inner template parameter.

Comment: careful with terminology, c++ does already define what a Container is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container

Comment: What about `auto add (const T& left, const U&right)` and let the compilation fail if the methods do not exist? Otherwise please create a [mcve] with the desired usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a `concept`:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <concepts>

template <typename C, typename T>
concept MyContainer = requires(C &c, const C &cc, std::size_t n)
{
    { cc.size() } -> std::same_as<std::size_t>;
    { c[n] } -> std::same_as<T &>;
    { cc[n] } -> std::same_as<const T &>;
};

float add(const MyContainer<int> auto &left, const MyContainer<float> auto &right) {}
```

Note that, rather than specifying the custom container requirements like this, it's better to rely on built-in concepts from `<ranges>`:

```
template <typename C, typename T>
concept MyContainer = std::ranges::random_access_range<C>
    && std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<C>, T>;

float add(MyContainer<int> auto &&left, MyContainer<float> auto &&right)
```

Comment: Why don't you use the simpler `{ ... } -> C` syntax, as in [`{ cc.size() } -> std::same_as<std::size_t>;`](https://godbolt.org/z/8KP3TK4cf)?

Comment: @chrysante Thanks, fixed. Because I remembered that it has quirky rules (acts as `decltype((x))` instead of `decltype(x)`), but didn't remember that it only matters for checking variable types.

Comment: [Wow, that seems crazy...](https://godbolt.org/z/71eKxsxo1)

Answer (score 3):

Your function expects that the type of the container must be instantiation of a template that can be instantiated with a single template argument. Many containers do not fit into that. For example `std::array` does not.

The issue with your attempt is that `std::vector` can be instantiated with 1 template argument, but only because there is a default for the allocator. You require that the template has exactly 1 type argument.

Sometimes more generic means more simple:

```
template <typename C1,typename C2>
float add(const C& left, const C2& right);
```

If you need the `value_type` the container should provide a member alias (standard containers do that). If some other container does not have that member alias, you can write a seperate trait to infer it. The function shouldnt care whether the type of the container is an instantiation of a template with 1, 2 or whatever number of template arguments.

If you need to restrict the function to work with containers where `C1::value_type == int` and `C2::value_type == float`, you can use SFINAE (the old way) or a requires expression (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/requires). The simple way is to add a `static_assert`.

PS: C++ does already define what a container is, see [named requirement Container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container). (I am not aware of a more modern container concept, but if it exists its also different from your notion of what makes a container)

Answer (score 3):

You can do almost exactly what you ask.

First define your concept for what makes a `MyContainer<T>`:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename ValueType>
concept MyContainer = requires(T t, std::size_t index) {
    { t.size() } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
    { std::as_const(t).size() } -> std::convertible_to<std::size_t>;
    { t[index] } -> std::same_as<ValueType&>;
    { std::as_const(t)[index] } -> std::same_as<const ValueType&>;
};
```

Then constrain your types to use this concept:

```cpp
float add(const MyContainer<int> auto& left, const MyContainer<float> auto& right);
```

---

But this is probably not what you actually want to do.

A standard concept you can use is [`std::ranges::input_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/input_range). This is used if you just want to iterate over the containers:

```cpp
float add(std::ranges::input_range<int> auto&& left, std::ranges::input_range<float> auto&& right);
```

And if you really need random access (indexing into the container), you can use [`std::ranges::random_access_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/random_access_range).

---

Or you can just use an unconstrained template:

```cpp
float add(const auto& left, const auto& right);
```

What does it matter to you if the left was actually a `std::vector<wrapper_class_convertible_to_int>` or `std::vector<short>` instead of `int`?

Answer (score 0):

The other answers using concepts are great, but pre-C++20 you have to use another way. First, define a type trait that checks for the required members:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename C, typename T, typename = void>
struct is_my_container : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename C, typename T>
struct is_my_container<C, T, std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<
    std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<C const>().size()), std::size_t>,
    std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<C const>()[std::declval<std::size_t>()]), T const&>,
    std::is_same<decltype(std::declval<C>()[std::declval<std::size_t>()]), T&>>>>
: std::true_type
{
};

template <typename C, typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_my_container_v = is_my_container<C, T>::value;
```

Because of [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), the specialization will only be generated if, after template argument substitution, the specialized argument would not cause a compile error. Missing members would cause a compile error and [`std::enable_if_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) would cause a compile error if the expression within it evaluated to `false` (which will happen if the members are present but have the wrong return types).

You can use the type trait with `std::enable_if_t` and SFINAE to cause your function not to be generated when the types of its arguments do not meet your container requirements:

```cpp
template <typename C1, typename C2, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<
    is_my_container<C1, int>,
    is_my_container<C2, float>>>>
float add(const C1&, const C2&)
```